# substract total amount from first_amount

Tags: javascript, php

in this below code i want to calculate remaining balance that is into a balance field. here i am using dynamic adding text fields and i want to add previously added text field values+ present values addition and subtract that into total_amount. please help me

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var rowCount = 1;
function addMoreRows(frm) {
rowCount ++;
var recRow = '<p id="rowCount'+rowCount+'"><input name="first_service[] '+rowCount+'" value="Payment '+rowCount+'" type="text" size="15" /> <input name="first_amount[]" id="first_amount" type="text" size="10"/> <input name="first_date[]" type="date" /> <select name="paid[]"> <option value="paid">Paid</option> <option value="unpaid">UnPaid</option></select><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="removeRow('+rowCount+');"><input type="button" value="-"></a></p>';
jQuery('#addedRows').append(recRow);
}

function removeRow(removeNum) {
jQuery('#rowCount'+removeNum).remove();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function calc() {
    
var total_amount = document.getElementById('total_amount').value;
     var first_amount = document.getElementById('first_amount').value;

var balance=(total_amount-first_amount);

 document.getElementById('balance').value =balance;
}
  </script>
```

```html
 <table  bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" width="68%" height="100" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5">
     <br><br>
       <tr>
                    <td align='right'>Company_Name</td> 
     <td>             
                    <input name="company_name" type="text"  value="<?php echo $company_name;?>" />
                </td>
                </tr>
    
                </tr>
     <tr >
                   <td align="right">Service_Name </td>
     <td>
                    <input type="text" name="service"  value="<?php echo $service;?>"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
    <tr >
                   <td align="right">Payment_Type </td>
     <td>
                    <input type="text" name="first_service" value="<?php echo $first_service;?>"/>
                  </td>
        </tr>
                <tr >
                   <td align="right">Payment</td>
     <td>
                    <input type="text" id="first_amount" name="first_amount" value="" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="calc();"/>
      </td>
     </td>                             
     
                </tr>
                
    <tr >
                   <td align="right">Payment_Date </td>
     <td>
                    <input type="date" name="first_date"  value="<?php echo $first_date;?>"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
    <tr >
    <td align="right">Balance_Due </td>
     <td>
                <input type="text" id="balance" name="balance"  value="" onkeyup="calc();"/>
    <td><select name="paid">
    <option value="paid">paid</option>
    <option value="unpaid">unpaid</option>
    </select>
    </td>
                                  
     </td>
                </tr>
    
    <tr >
                   <td align="right">Total_Amount </td>
     <td>
                    <input type="text" id="total_amount" name="total_amount"  value="<?php echo $total_amount;?>"/>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <td><td class="link"><input type="submit" name="Update"  value="Update" /> <a href="payment_details.php?company_name=<?php echo $company_name;?>">Cancel</a> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
     </div>
          </form>
```

```
<td><input type="text" name="first_service[]" value="Payment 1" size="15" >
<input type="text" name="first_amount[]" id="first_amount" placeholder="Amount" size="10" onkeyup="calc()">
<input type="date" name="first_date[]" size="20"> <select name="paid[]" ><option value="paid">Paid</option><option value="unpaid">UnPaid</option></select> <input type="button" value="+" onclick="addMoreRows(this.form);">
<div id="addedRows"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your `addMoreRows` function you can add more than one elements that will contain the `first_amount` value. You are using `first_amount[]` in name to keep all `first_amount` value in array but using same id for all that is wrong. ID must be unique in HTML.  So first resolve these issue.

Then in script first get the length of `first_amount` elements and then add their values. Then do whatever you want to do.